# EntityManagerFactory is null with hibernate osgi and eclipse-bundle using equinox

Tags: hibernate, osgi, entitymanager, persistence-provider

I m trying to implement hibernate-osgi with Equinox.

I've created a plugin "**my.app.hibernate.osgi**" from the following jars:
[jars of my.app.hibernate.osgi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCZLv.png)

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar
- classmate-1.3.0.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-osgi-5.2.16.Final.jar
- jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
- javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
- javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
- jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
- junit-3.8.1.jar
- validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar

In the **MANIFEST.MF** of this plugin I've added the following:

```
Bundle-Name: my.app.hibernate.osgi
Bundle-SymbolicName: my.app.hibernate.osgi;singleton:=true
Bundle-Activator: org.hibernate.osgi.HibernateBundleActivator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

Then I've created another plugin "**my.app.core.hibernate**" for my hibernate configuration, Entities and DAOs

In the **MANIFEST.MF** of this one, it is like this:

```
Bundle-Activator: my.app.core.hibernate.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: my.app.hibernate.osgi
Require-Bundle: my.app.hibernate.osgi
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services,
 org.eclipse.osgi,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.core.net,
...
Meta-Persistence: META_INF/persistence.xml
```

And my **persistence.xml** :

```xml
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="myAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     ...
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have also a EntityManagerService to get EntityManager

```java
private static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    if ( emf == null ) {
        Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( EntityManagerService.class );
        BundleContext context = thisBundle.getBundleContext();

        ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference( PersistenceProvider.class.getName() );
        PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = (PersistenceProvider) context.getService( serviceReference );

        emf = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory( "myAppPU", null );
    }
    return emf;
}
```

Finally I have a third plugin "**my.app.core**" that uses my DAOs.
With the following **MANIFEST.MF** :

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: my.app.hibernate.core
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: my.app.core.hibernate,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.fx.core.di;bundle-version="2.2.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,
 org.apache.log4j,
 javax.inject,
 org.apache.commons.lang,
 org.eclipse.equinox.app
```

When I start my app

```java
    emf = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory( "myAppPU", null );
```

the entityManagerFactory is null

What am I doing wrong?

(Edited:)
I figured out (while debugging the hibernate code) that in ProviderChercker the following line returns null:

```java
    final String setting = (String) integration.get( AvailableSettings.PROVIDER );
```

What provider should I declare in the persistence.xml ?

I m using a embedded H2 db V.1.4.197

*(Also, I m not sure whether I should include the two following jars org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar and org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar to my "my.app.hibernate.osgi" plugin.
I've tried but in that case I have a ClassCastException : HibernateBundleActivator cannot be cast to BundleActivator)*

Answer (score 0):

The provider name was bad.
The good one:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```